# How to resolve warning Port 2 (s) of mux2to1 expects 2 bits, got 1 in Verilog?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, multiplexer

I have tried to implement a 16to1 mux using two 8to1 mux's and 1 2to1 mux. The Verilog compiler generated:

```
warning: Port 2 (s) of mux2to1 expects 2 bits, got 1.  
 : Padding 1 high bits of the port.
```

I don't understand how to fix this error as the reference code is very similar to the one I have used. The simulator used for generating the waveforms is gtkwave. All mux's are saved in the same file. Verilog and Testbench code are attached below:

file name:mux16to1e3.v
Verilog code:

```
module mux16to1e3(w,s,f);
input [15:0] w;
input [3:0] s;
output f;
wire [1:0] x;

mux8to1 m1(w[7:0],s[2:0],x[0]);
mux8to1 m2(w[15:8],s[2:0],x[1]);
mux2to1 m3(x,s[3],f);

endmodule

module mux8to1(w,s,f);
input [7:0] w;
input [2:0] s;
output f;
reg f;
always @(w or s)
case(s)
0: f =w[0];
1: f =w[1];
2: f =w[2];
3: f =w[3];
4: f =w[4];
5: f =w[5];
6: f =w[6];
7: f =w[7];
endcase 
endmodule

module mux2to1(w,s,f);
input [1:0] w;
input [1:0] s;
output f;
reg f;
always @(w or s)
if(s==0)
f = w[0];
else 
f = w[1];
endmodule
```

file name:exercise3_tb.v

Testbench code:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
`include "mux16to1e3.v"
module exercise3_tb();
reg [15:0] w;
reg [3:0] s;
wire f;

mux16to1e3 test(w,s,f);
initial
begin
$dumpfile("exercise3.vcd");
$dumpvars(0,exercise3_tb);
 w = 16'b0000000000000001; s = 4'b0000;#20;
    w = 16'b1000000000000000; s = 4'b1111;#20;
    w = 16'b0000000000000100; s = 4'b0010;#20;
    w = 16'b0010000000000000; s = 4'b1101;#20;

    $display("Test Complete");

end
endmodule
```

Output generated:

```
     iverilog -o exercise3_tb.vvp exercise3_tb.v
./mux16to1e3.v:9: warning: Port 2 (s) of mux2to1 expects 2 bits, got 1.
./mux16to1e3.v:9:        : Padding 1 high bits of the port.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In mux2to1, you've specified `s` to be 2 bits, when you only need 1.

> input [1:0] s;

So change that to `input s;`